# Get list of Booleans corresponding to list of multiple-and-duplicate regex patterns

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

Given a list of regex patterns **that includes duplicate patterns** and a single input string.

How can I get a Booleans list (with the same length as input list of regex patterns) where each Boolean corresponds to whether or not a regex pattern (at the same index) from the regex list matched the input string?

I want to do this for each string in a pandas Series or DataFrame column.

The following code *almost* does exactly what I want, but it does not match the second (or n'th) occurrence of a duplicate regex pattern, only the first.

I want to avoid solutions that use a for loop.

```py
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series([
    'one two three four five six seven', 
    'seven six five four three two one twenty ten'])

# list of regex patterns (note: 'one' is duplicated)
pattern_list = ['three', 'one', 'no_match', 'not_in', 'five', 'one']
pattern_single = '(' + ')|('.join(pattern_list) + ')'

pattern_single
```

```py
'(three)|(one)|(no_match)|(not_in)|(five)|(one)'
```

```py
((~a.str.extractall(pattern_single).isna())
    .reset_index()
    .groupby('level_0').agg('sum')
    .drop(columns='match')
    .values.tolist())
```

```
[[True, True, False, False, True, False],
 [True, True, False, False, True, False]]
```

when what I want is:

```
[[True, True, False, False, True, True],
 [True, True, False, False, True, True]]
```

---

I have tried wrapping each `<pattern>` separated by `|` with `((?<![\w\d])<pattern>(?![\w\d]))` which produces the same results.

I have tried wrapping each `<pattern>` with `((?=.*<pattern>))` with and without the separating `|` which does not capture anything.

I have also tried using naming each of the groups as below: same results.

```py
pattern_list = ['<{}>{}'.format(chr(k+97), v) for k,v in enumerate(pattern_list)]
pattern_single = '(?P' + ')*|(?P'.join(pattern_list) + ')'

pattern_single
```

```py
'(?P<a>three)*|(?P<b>one)*|(?P<c>no_match)*|(?P<d>not_in)*|(?P<e>five)*|(?P<f>one)'
```

Comment: add a quatifier to catch multiples? Maybe use http://regex101.com to foolproof your regex against your data

Comment: `'(' + ')*|('.join(pattern_list) + ')'` produces the same.  I did use regex101, it matches the first, second, ..., nth occurrence, but that just highlights the single occurrence in the sample text, and does not tell me which patterns matched.

Comment: From the OP: `['three', 'one', 'no_match', 'not_in', 'five', 'one']` 'one' is repeated twice: in the second and sixth position.

Comment: Misread. Not possible - you look for a regex that has different optional groupings where 2 of them are identical. The first group that matches resolves the match. You cannot match "earlier" and "later" identical groups, it will always match with the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, as [Patrick Artner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7505395/patrick-artner) commented, this cannot be done with regex patterns, here is an answer that at least gives what I am after.

Changed the input slightly to show different output for cases where there are different matches, and for cases where there are no matches.

If someone else has a more efficient timed solution, I would accept that as the answer.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

b = pd.Series([
    'one two three four five six seven', 
    'there is no match in this example text',
    'seven six five four three one twenty ten',
    'also no matching strings'])

pattern_list = ['three', 'one', 'no_match', 'not_in', 'five', 'one', 'two']
pattern_single = '(' + ')|('.join(pattern_list) + ')'

first_match = (
    (~b.str.extractall(pattern_single).isna())
    .reset_index()
    .groupby('level_0').agg('sum')
    .drop(columns='match')
    .reindex(range(b.size), fill_value=False)
    .values)

first_ptrn_index = [pattern_list.index(x) for x in pattern_list]

indx_mtch = lambda vec: vec[first_ptrn_index]

np.apply_along_axis(indx_mtch, 1, first_match).tolist()
```

```
[[True, True, False, False, True, True, True],
 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
 [True, True, False, False, True, True, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
```